# Catching UnauthorizedAccessError in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I would like to find all of the files within a specified directory and store the full path of any folders/files that throw an access denied error (like the one shown below).

```
Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\SystemKeys' is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\SystemKeys"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\ProgramData\...ypto\SystemKeys:String) [Get-ChildItem], Unauthoriz
   edAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

The command I am using is:

```
$Allfiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $Directories -Recurse -Force -File | % { $_.FullName }
```

I have had a few ideas:

- Parsing the `$error` variable for `DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand exceptions`
- Using the parameters `-ErrorVariable` and `-ErrorAction`
- Using `try{} catch{}`
- using $_

But I have not made much progress with this and I was wondering if you could help.

Thanks,

TheCube

Comment: [1] seeing the code you have tried - and what did not work - would help quite a bit. [*grin*] [2] why did you add so many PoSh version? are you _really_ using them all for this?

Comment: Hi Lee_Dailey thanks for the reply. I didn't add the rest of my script becasue I didn't think it was relevant sorry. I added all of the PS versions because I thought that it would increase the liklihood of people seeing my question.

Comment: the extra - likely unneeded - tags REDUCE the help you will get. [*grin*] making code that will work on all the varied PoSh versions is difficult ... and few folks have access to the older versions. that is **_especially true for ps2 now that it is removed from win10_**. ///// i'm glad to see that mklement0 was able to help you ... kool! [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Use -ErrorVariable errs to collect all errors in variable $errs.
# -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue silences display output of the errors.
$allfiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $Directories -Recurse -Force -File -ErrorVariable errs -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# List all paths that resulted in an unauthorized-access exception.
# Note: Given that other errors are unlikely to occur, you could omit the 
#       `where` call.
$errs | where { $_.Exception -is [UnauthorizedAccessException] } |
  select -ExpandProperty TargetObject
```